# rails s hangs - Hartl Rails Guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I'm a beginner and just installed everything on my system (new) per the Hartl guide.  I am having issues with 'rails s' - it hangs and doesn't continue so I'm unable to do anything except end the command line processes and start over.  Here's where it stops:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on (localhost3000)
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-01-03 00:13:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-01-03 00:13:30] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
[2014-01-03 00:13:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22805 port=3000


Started GET "/microposts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:38 -0800
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by MicropostsController#new as HTML
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
  Rendered microposts/_form.html.erb (71.3ms)
  Rendered microposts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (90.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 237ms (Views: 222.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/microposts.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:39 -0800


Started GET "/assets/microposts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:13:40 -0800


Started GET "/microposts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:11 -0800
Processing by MicropostsController#new as HTML
  Rendered microposts/_form.html.erb (6.1ms)
  Rendered microposts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 17.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/microposts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/microposts.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-03 00:19:12 -0800
```

Comment: At least from the log, it doesn't really show any indication that the server is hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run "rails s" it takes over the terminal and doesn't return.  You should open a second terminal if you want to run other commands at the same time.

In production you usually setup rails with apache or nginx.  See this guide for more information:

http://rubyonrails.org/deploy

Answer (score 1):

As stated, rails server takes over the terminal when you run it. You've got to start a new terminal session. A quit step in ubuntu/linux is the combination

```
 CTL+SHIFT+T
```

or

```
CTL+ALT+T
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question at first.  It look like it's hanging but that actually means that it's running.  As long as it looks like it's hanging it is running the server and you can open the localhost:3000 to see your webpage locally.  When you're ready to shutdown the server and get your prompt back you can click control c on the mac.